# Ajax request before submitting is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have to pass a variable that is not in my form so i used an ajax request before submitting

```
$("#bouton").click(function(){
        dureechoisi = $("#duree1").text().replace(/\D/g,'');
        alert(dureechoisi);
            $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "/iframe/simu-test.php",
            data : {
                dureechoisi1 : dureechoisi
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
            },
            async: true
        });
         $("#resultatform").submit(); 
    });
```

to get my variable : `$dureechoisi = $_POST['dureechoisi1'];`

My post variable is empty, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: probably you have to submit the form after the ajax success

Comment: when I included the submit part after success the form is not submitted does is mean that it's a url problem  that he can't find the file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ajax before submit, you use ajax's callback becase ajax is asynchronous function.

You can do this.

```
$("#bouton").click(function(){
    dureechoisi = $("#duree1").text().replace(/\D/g,'');
    alert(dureechoisi);
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "/iframe/simu-test.php",
        data : {
            dureechoisi1 : dureechoisi
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
        },
        async: true,
        success: function() {
            $("#resultatform").submit(); 
        }
    });
});
```

read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: I tried this code and now not only i don't get the variable but also the form is not submitted

Comment: @Jihane ajax request - response is ok? is it statusCode = 200?

Comment: No , no success :/